# How to quickly resolve dependencies issues in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I inherited an android project with a ton of dependencies. I often waste a lot of time, because of finding dependencies that are conflicting. Can I somehow quickly diagnose which dependencies are conflicting?

Comment: Did you start with a good old `gradle dependencies` ?

Comment: Also, do you have an example project that shows the conflicting dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I've tried gradle dependencies. However, it didn't work for me or I don't know how to use it efficiently. E.g. I had a conflict with apache commons-io. I took the output from gradle dependencies and was looking for different versions of the library (to know where to do exclude), but all listed commons-io had the same version?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a sample project. My project that causes problems consists 3 modules and a ton of dependencies. I'm asking about the generic approach to deal with such a dependencies hell.

Comment: I don't know such generic approach and looking for example to experiment.